# when i see my website inside a VWD designer it works fine but on debugging or running the website it gives me only text

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web

Question:- Please help me out of this problem

i have a question and is unable to find the answer.
i used google for a long for the answer but was answer less. can any one answer my question.
i am using Dotnet 2010 (RTMrel Full Version) and have created a website as sample using some of
the pictures and text in it. when i see my website inside a VWD designer it works fine but on
debugging or running the website it gives me only text. the images i used are not shown on the web page.
also the website i created inside dotnet 2008 (Full version) on importing gives the same error.

please can any one answer my simple question.

Comment: Where did you store the images, which folder?  Also when you run the website, on the blank images, see the path and tell us where it is looking for them. Are you running the site through IIS, or using Visual Studio and hitting F5 to run it?

Comment: i am having a big folder structures in my project like website->dll/, images/, aspx files, css/, js/, etc etc. and i just tried to run a single page while selecting and right select for applying to run using broswer with in the editor. also the same is not working for pressing f5 and have tried for other pages as well. if is there any programm or software which can stop from vs 2008 but i unistalled it completely from system.

Comment: all of the images are linked from the images/image1/, images/image2/ etc folders and i have a central location in c:/denno/Visualstudio2010/websites/ to get access for all of the projects and websites.

Comment: even the images used using css for tag <td id="image132" ......., <asp:Image id=..  runat="server"  ImageUrl="Images/Image1.jpg" .... and <img src="images/image1/get.jpg" ...... are not working.

Comment: do you have you images in app_themes folder? Otherwise try one thing, locate one of the images in VS in source view, remove the html code and manually put it back in the code view, not using designer.  when you do src= Visual Studio should prompt you to select the image, select it and see how the path it makes looks.  run the application if this image works update the others to have the same path.

Comment: yes, i do have a app_themes folder, yeah sure let me try. should i have to move images to this folder.

Comment: try to use the code side to make the image tag in the html and see if that helps, you can leave the images outside of App_Themes, i thought if they were inside it might be a authorization issue, but if outside that's not it.

Comment: sorry even a single image is also not shown in the same i took 2 days to get out of this but no result. i am using HP laptop 2000 series 2020 model with windows7 installed. installed vs2010 RTMrel and using SQl server 2005 with an Upgrade to SQL Server 2008 R2. i think this could be due to my system. i have removed RTMrel and is back to VS 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as i have noticed, VS 2010 RTMrel has some of the compatibility issue with VS 2008 (+ SP1), so please don't install both on the same system. prefare to uninstall all of the previous versions from the system and then install the RTMrel on the system (what i tried my self). this could solve your problem.

Comment: also you can link back to the link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ajay_pathak/archive/2011/08/06/website-deployed-on-iis-7-5-not-showing-images-and-css-files.aspx

Comment: another one 

http://forums.asp.net/t/1016759.aspx/1?image+not+showing+on+web+page+at+runtime+

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371337/background-image-is-not-displayed-in-firefox

Comment: thank you for the help as it solved my ever lasting problem. as you predicted, yes i was using both the softwares on the same system also i had tried the same after wards. but when i uninstalled all of the related softwares (dot-net, SQL, etc) it solved the problem.