# CSS Background URL does not work in Firefox

Tags: css, background, icons, background-image

Please explain to me why this does not work in FireFox

```
<img class="icon-expand" />
```

CSS

```
.icon-expand {
    background: url('../images/expand-plus-icon-24.png') no-repeat;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 3px;
}
```

Chrome, Edge and IE11 show it fine. But why FireFox acting silly and shows nothing? Path is correct.

Answer (score 1):

**Some Considerations: `<img>` tags and inlining styles**

Since you are using an actual `<img>` tag, you may want to consider either explicitly setting the `src` attribute to your target URL as opposed to using a CSS class :

```
 <img src='{your-expand-url}' />
```

Firefox is likely more strict when it comes to rendering `<img>` tags by requiring that they have an `src` attribute :

```
<img src='' class='icon-expand' />
```

You'll notice if you include a blank one that you receive the following :

[image]

Likewise, you could consider explicitly causing the element to render without a `src` attribute by using the `display: block` property on your CSS class :

```
.icon-expand {
    background: url('../images/expand-plus-icon-24.png') no-repeat;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 3px;
    /* This will cause your element to render as expected */
    display: block;
}
```

**The Solution: Use a `<div>`**

Since you are using background URLs through CSS, you should consider just using a `<div>` or similar element as opposed to an `<img>` tag, which is designed to target an image directly :

```
<div class="icon-expand"></div>
```

**Example**

```css
.icon-expand {
  background: url('http://megaicons.net/static/img/icons_sizes/8/60/24/imagetools-expand-icon.png') no-repeat;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-expand"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try like this:

```
.icon-expand {
  background: url('../images/expand-plus-icon-24.png') no-repeat;
  display: block;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 3px;
}
```

or maybe this topic could help you: [Background image is not displayed in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371337/background-image-is-not-displayed-in-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

`<img>` is an inline element.

If you want to have background image set to it [you should add a `display: block`](https://jsfiddle.net/5zpz4eys/5/) to the css.

This is not highly recommended though.

Unless you are certain that you want to use an `<img>` with `background` you better choose another option like [changing it to a `<div>`](https://jsfiddle.net/5zpz4eys/6/) or [use the `src` attribute](https://jsfiddle.net/5zpz4eys/7/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<div class="icon-expand" />
```