# background url not rendering in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am having an issue getting a background url to render in Firefox for my [website](https://gastromend.herokuapp.com) whilst it works fine in Safari and Chrome.

I have looked through several of the stack posts on this subject namely [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907833/content-url-does-not-display-image-on-firefox-browsern) and [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371337/background-image-is-not-displayed-in-firefox) and none of the initiatives in these posts have worked thus far.

**my html**

```
<div class="jumbotron">

    <div style="" class="animated fadeInDown">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-12">

                <h1>Curing H-pylori <br class="visible-lg "/>Parasite and Gastrointestinal Infections</h1>
                <hr style="width:25%;text-align:left;margin:30px 0; border:2.5px solid #fff;"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <h2 class="subtitle">Take the step to recovery.</h2>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**my css**

```
.jumbotron {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 450px;
    background: url('https://s122939.gridserver.com/clients/conversant/images/driving.jpg') center center;
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 1;
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0;
    polygon(0 0%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 85%);
    clip-path: url(#poly);
    overflow: hidden;

}
```

I have also tried a host of other things to get the image to render without success before asking for help here.

1. Deleted my Firefox cached data
2. Changed my css to `display: block;`
3. Checked to ensure that their is no add on blocking in Firefox.
4. Used `background: fixed;`
5. Used `jumbotron::before`
6. Tried `content: url`

Any steering or help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1) can you try to post a fiddle?
2) your browser makes a request to the image file in order to load it, check in firefox dev tool if the file is being loaded at all

Comment: try to remove `center center` and use background-image instead of background .. also what is polygon alone like that ? it should be used withon clip-path

Comment: your code seems to work here - https://jsfiddle.net/Lah45n5k/

Comment: ok i see, the issue is with clip path ... for chrome you are using the clip path correctly with webkit .. but firefox will use the standard one which is not working ... change `clip-path: url(#poly);` by `clip-path: polygon( ... );`

Comment: @TemaniAfif how do you mean

Comment: Add jumbotron::after with the content: url instead of before for your css for the image to render in firefox.

Comment: Ahhhh I see, thank you very much @TemaniAfif really appreciate that. that worked and it now renders

Comment: thanks for the steering the rest of the guys,

Comment: Can this question be closed now? If the problem was caused by a simple error in the CSS, it won't be of much use to others, especially since the question itself doesn't contain all the CSS needed to reproduce the problem accurately.

Comment: yes............